# Automapper 9 Configuration

Tags: c#, automapper-9

In previous versions of AutoMapper I used to be able to configure AutoMapper like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperFactory
{
    public static IConfigurationProvider CreateMapperConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            //Scan *.UI assembly for AutoMapper Profiles
            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutoMapperFactory));

            cfg.AddProfiles(assembly);

            cfg.IgnoreAllUnmapped();
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

Now, the line that says `cfg.AddProfiles(assembly)` is giving me the error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AutoMapper.Profile>`

How can I get an `IEnumerable<AutoMapper.Profile>` to pass as a parameter for `AddProfiles`?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration

Comment: I saw that, but it just says "myAssembly" as the parameter.  Isn't that the same as `assembly` for me?

Comment: It seems this `cfg.AddProfiles(assembly);` turned into this `cfg.AddMaps(assembly);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the addMaps, instead of addProfile, like this:

```
public static class AutoMapperFactory
{
    public static IConfigurationProvider CreateMapperConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            //Scan *.UI assembly for AutoMapper Profiles
            var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutoMapperFactory));

            cfg.AddMaps(assembly);

            cfg.IgnoreAllUnmapped();
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

As stated in the documentation:

> Configuration inside a profile only applies to maps inside the
>   profile. Configuration applied to the root configuration applies to
>   all maps created.

And can be created as classes with specific type maps.

Comment: Any ideas on how to tell one profile to use another profile for one of its properties?